# instagrapi получение подписок на хештеги

Tags: python, instagram, hashtag

Использую следующий код

```
from instagrapi import Client
cl = Client()
cl.login(ACCOUNT_USERNAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
user_id = cl.user_id_from_username('test_account')
following = cl.user_following(user_id, 20)
cl.logout()

for key, user_short in following.items():
    username = user_short.username
    full_name = user_short.full_name
    #print(f'Ключ: {key}, username: {username}, full_name: {full_name}')
    print(f'username: {username}')
```

на выходе получаю список подписок на аккаунты. Однако в инстаграмм можно подписаться на хештеги. Как получить **список подписок на хештеги**. В https://subzeroid.github.io/instagrapi/usage-guide/user.html ответа не нашел.